# Google Sheets, make list of unique values from two columns

Tags: google-sheets, unique

Google Sheets:

Col B:B has a ton of duplicate values and in col A10 I need to get a list of unique values from B:B.

formula =unique(filter(FLATTEN(B:B,A$9:A9),FLATTEN(B:B,A$9:A9)<>"",FLATTEN(B:B,A$9:A9)<>"Header"))
works and creates a list of all the unique values.

But can I have an empty row between the results?
for example A10="Madrid", A11="", A12="Barcelona", A13="", etc

It creates a list of unique values.
I also tried to copy and paste every other row the formula =index(unique(filter(FLATTEN(B:B,A$9:A9),FLATTEN(B:B,A$9:A9)<>"",FLATTEN(B:B,A$9:A9)<>"Header")),1,1) but it gives the first unique result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=LET(u,UNIQUE(B:B),TOCOL({u,ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(u/0))}))
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much, can someone explain what this formula is exactly doing?